# ¿Como usar ofuscación con proguard y JACK?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8

Estoy probando Jack en android studio puedo generar el app-release.apk con este build.gradle sin problema, pero a la hora de ejecutarla crashea:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.personal.project"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Si desactivo minify no hay ningun fallo, pero el apk pasa a ocupar mas del doble de tamaño...

añado logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.my.personal.project, PID: 19382
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.personal.project/com.my.personal.project.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.af.o(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.a.setContentView(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.my.personal.project.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.af.o(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.a.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at com.my.personal.project.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.af.o(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.a.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at com.my.personal.project.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                   at android.support.design.internal.c.b(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.af.o(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.a.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at com.my.personal.project.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                   at android.support.design.internal.c.b(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.af.o(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.a.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at com.my.personal.project.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                   at android.support.design.internal.c.b(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.af.o(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.c.a.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at com.my.personal.project.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class android.support.v7.widget.r because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'android.support.v7.widget.r' appears in /data/app/com.my.personal.project-2/base.apk)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.bw.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                at and
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.my.personal.project.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.my.personal.project.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

nav_header_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Mas información:

Si añado -dontobfuscate a proguard-android.txt la aplicación funciona correctamente, aqui dice que Jack soporta obfuscation http://source.android.com/source/jack.html

¿De que forma puedo usar la ofuscación con proguard?

Comment: puedes agregar la información de la exception?

Comment: El generar el .apk es independiente a si tiene algún problema tu aplicación, no te informa de algún problema tu LogCat? de otra forma sería difícil saber la causa.

Comment: @Elenasys
He añadido el logcat, de todas formas el error se da solo al activar el minify, por lo que supongo que es ahi donde se origina el fallo, si desactivo minify la aplicación se ejecuta sin ningun problema ni error de ningun tipo

Comment: Gracias, ve mi respuesta, tienes que agregar tus layout de NavigationView y NavigationMenuView por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución fue agregar esta linea al final del archivo de proguard

-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por agregar tu mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat, en realidad el problema es la aplicación, estos son los problemas:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16:
>   Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

y

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17:
>   Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView

El layout que carga `NavigationView` y `NavigationMenuView` tiene un problema para poder inflarse.

Pendiente de revisar los layout para definir el problema real...

Comment: He añadido todos los archivos xml que carga mainactivity, de todas formas, si hago build de la app sin activar proguard no hay ningun problema, por lo que creo que el fallo puede estar ahí, tal vez algo que se me haya pasado por alto y no sea compatible con JACK...

Comment: He hecho algunos avances, los he añadido al mensaje original